Why am I getting this wrong number or argument column sort error?
I followed this sortable column tutorial http://railscasts.com/episodes/228-sortable-table-columns?view=asciicast
The column sorting worked fine until I added in the helper section. I now get this error:
index.html.erbwhere line #20 raised:

wrong number of arguments (given 1, expected 3..4)
Extracted source (around line #2):
              
module SortHelper
  def sortable(relation, column, title, options = {})
    matching_column = column.to_s == params[:sort]
    direction = if matching_column
      (params[:direction] == "asc") ? "desc" : "asc"
    else # Ascending by default if switching columns

This is the index.html:
              <tr>
    line 20     <th><%= sortable "name" %></th>
                <th><%= sortable "street" %></th>
                <th><%= sortable "city" %></th>
                <th><%= sortable "state" %></th>
                <th><%= sortable "zip" %></th>
                <th><%= sortable "list" %></th>
                <th><%= sortable "website" %></th>
              </tr>

This is the helper:
  def sortable(column, title = nil)
    title ||= column.titleize
    direction = column == sort_column && sort_direction == "asc" ? "desc" : "asc"
    link_to title, :sort => column, :direction => direction
  end

Code added to controller:
  helper_method :sort_column, :sort_direction (at top)

  def index
    @clubs = Club.order(params[:sort])
  end


private:
  def sort_column
      Club.column_names.include?(params[:sort]) ? params[:sort] : "name"
  end

  def sort_direction
      %w[asc desc].include?(params[:direction]) ?  params[:direction] : "asc"
  end

The error is saying it should have 3-4 arguments but the helper is only for 2 at most. So what gives? What am I missing?

Looks like it's picking up a different sortable helper method. Have you searched for module SortHelper? Perhaps it's a gem? Is your sortable part of the ApplicationHelper module?

Your mystery code matches this SortHelper module.

Looks like you're right. Not sure how that other module got in there but you're right it's there. I'm going to delete the one from the tutorial and try and use this module. Thx.

Just a tip but you might want to find newer tutorials. Yes, Ryan Bates did a good job but it was 14 years ago and both Ruby and Rails are very different from back then.

This is because your
def sortable(relation, column, title, options = {})
expects 3 required params: relation, column and title, and 1 optional options
But you call this method with just 1 argument sortable "name"

Is "sortable 'name'" the relation or column part? I don't know what the "relation" part means. Can you give me an example of what the 3 required params are?

first things first, read about methods, passing positional and keyword arguments, 2) relation is usually like a AR collection, 3) is it your sortable method?
